# ZF3, ¿Cómo incluir librerias propias?

Tags: php, zend

Estoy lidiando tratando de incluir extensiones dentro de un proyecto Z3 pero no consigo hacerlo. Se que en principio habría 2 alternativas:

> a) tener la libreria en modo local, en algún sitio de mi disco.
>
> b) trabajar en modo repositorio con Github por ejemplo.

Por el momento, para agilizar un poco los primeros trabajos y el aprendizaje, prefiero trabajar en alternativa "a". Pero no consigo apuntarla correctamente.

Lo que hice:

Bajo htdocs, cree una nueva carpeta "librerias/zf3/extesiones/".
Ahi cree el archivo "AbstractActionProjectController.php" que es una extensión de "AbstractActionControlle.php".

Bajo htdocs, cree un proyecto "prueba" a traves de composeer:
composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application .

Modifique composer.json, quedando algo así:

```
 ...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
        "zendframeworkme\\": "../librerias/zf3/extesiones/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/test/",
        "zendframeworkme\\": "..librerias/zf3/extesiones/"
    }
},
...
```

ejecute:
composer dump-autoload

Modifique /module/Application/src/Controller/IndexController.php :
namespace Application/Controller;

```
include "AbstractActionProjectControllerController.php";

// use AbstractActionProjectControllerController; // no me anduvo tampoco

use Zend/View/Model/ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionProjectController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        die( "Estoy en indexAction" );
    }
}
```

Finalmente me dice que no encuentra la clase:

> Warning: include(AbstractActionProjectControllerController. php): failed to open stream: No existe el archivo o el directorio in /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf3-mod-user/module/Application/src/Controller/IndexController.php on line 13

Bueno, gracias, espero alguno pueda/sepa ayudarme.

Comment: Sería interesante de cara a que conocieras más sobre el funcionamiento de stackoverflow hacer el [Recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Si la respuesta aporta información para solucionar el problema, una buena forma de agradecerlo es votando de forma positiva. Y si es la que te ha resuelto el problema, márcala con el ✅.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es crear la estructura de directorios siguiendo el standard de *Zend Framework*:

**1.- Crear directorios**

```
mkdir -p librerias/zf3/Extensiones/src/Action
```

Quedaría una estructura así:

```
.
├── config
├── data
├── librerias
├── librerias
│   └── zf3
│       └── Extensiones
│           └── src
│               └── Action
├── module
└── vendor
```

**2.- En *composer.json***

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
        "Extensiones\\": "librerias/zf3/Extesiones/src/"
    }
},
```

**3.- Ejecutas el composer del proyecto:**

```
composer dump-autoload
```

O:

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

*Dependiendo de tu instalación de php usarás php, php56, php7, etc.*

**4.- Preparas la clase a extender.**

El controlador debe extender a *AbstractActionController* por lo que, la clase nueva que quieres extender debe extender dicha clase:

```
<?php

namespace Extensiones\Action;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

abstract class AbstractActionProjectController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return 'Yeah!!';
    }
}
```

**5.- El controlador que quiere extender la clase nueva:**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Extensiones\Action\AbstractActionProjectController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionProjectController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $viewModel = new ViewModel();

        $viewModel->setVariable('message', $this->getMessage());

        return $viewModel;
    }
}
```

#### ¿Cuál es la teoría?

La definición en el *json* especifica el inicio del *namespace (1)* y a partir de que directorio se estructura el resto del *namespace (2)* a partir del *root path* del proyecto.

```
"Extensiones\\": "librerias/zf3/Extesiones/src/"
 └── (1)          └── (2)
```

Así que cualquier clase dentro de una estructura similar a esta:

```
librerias
└── zf3
    └── Extensiones
        └── src
            ├── Action
            ├── Controller
            ├── Entity
            ├── Form
            ├── Listener
            ├── Model
            ├── Plugin
            ├── Validator
            └── ViewHelper
```

Sería llamada mediante el *namespace* seguido de la estructura de directorios y nombre de la clase `Extensiones\<NombreDirectorio>\<nombreDeLaClase>`

```
Extensiones\Action\<nombreDeLaClase>
Extensiones\Controller\<nombreDeLaClase>
Extensiones\Entity\<nombreDeLaClase>
Extensiones\Form\<nombreDeLaClase>
//...
```

Si no me he saltado ningún paso, siguiendo estos pasos deberías poder crear cualquier tipo de estructura fuera del clásico módulo inicial.

Comment: WOUU!!! buenísima tu respuesta Oscar! 


Es muy didáctica. Muchísimas gracias.


Ahora te comento un error que me aparece. He seguido los pasos que me indicaste, y en el IndexController que usa la extensión,  me aparece:
Fatal error: Class 'Extensiones\Action\AbstractActionProjectController' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf3-mod-user/module/Application/src/Controller/IndexController.php on line 18

Comment: Ohhh tenía mal escrita una palabra.     
Ya me funciona bien.   GENIAL. GRACIAS!          Dime, y ¿cómo podría hacer si quisiera poner la libreria fuera de la carpeta del proyecto, a modo de poder utilizarla en otros proyectos, y no tener que copiarla dentro de cada uno de ellos?

Comment: @Mauricio en ese caso yo cambiaría el planteamiento, porque si cambias después el proyecto de entorno no funcionaría. El directorio dentro del proyecto. Y dos opciones, o un repositorio, donde los cambios son clonados en cada proyecto, o el directorio como enlace simbólico a un directorio externo con las librerías. Si montas el proyecto en un servidor, solo deberás añadir el contenido que tenía ese directorio y todo funcionando!

Comment: Buenísimo Oscar !!!  Muchísimas gracias!!!!

Comment: Aunque he hecho el recorrido de StackOverflow, no veo dónde como marcar la respuesta positivamente. ✅?

Comment: @Mauricio en la parte superior de cada pregunta/respuesta a la izquierda aparecen un indicador apuntando hacia arriba (voto positivo), un 0 debajo o el número de votos recibidos, y debajo otro indicador apuntando hacia abajo (boto negativo). En cada respuesta a tus preguntas, debajo de esos indicadores deberías ver un ✔️ de color gris. Ese símbolo cuando lo marcas es para aceptar una respuesta que ha solucionado el problema. Son independientes las votaciones y la aceptación de respuesta. Cualquier cosa no dudes en preguntar.